# beginInvoke works but doesn't write value to a variable

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've got a thread function. Inside this function I'm trying to use `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke` method with `BeginInvoke` because I can't use it directly in thread function. But  variable `settings` is always "". It shows messagebox so BeginInvoke works normal. But why It doesn't write anything to variable?

```
Thread.Sleep(15000);
if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Try to reload data!")));
string obpath = "C:\\program files\\windows sidebar\\Gadgets\\res.txt";
            string path1 = "C:\\program files\\windows sidebar\\Gadgets\\settings.txt";
string settings = "";
if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => settings = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ReadFile", new object[] { path1 }) as string));
```

Comment: When did you checked the  value in settings? directly after stepping over the BeginInvoke? Remember, BeginInvoke just pushes the Action on a stack of actions, that will be processed at a later point. You can use Invoke to halt your current thread and wait until the Dispatcher has processed your action.

Answer (score 1):

BeginInvoke executes asynchronously, meaning it queues the action into the dispatcher and returns immediately. If you need the result, you can use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

You should note that using `Invoke` is considered a bad practice - unless absolutely necessary. You're wasting a lot of time on a thread waiting for synchronization. Consider refactoring your code so this wouldn't happen (e.g. by putting all of this code inside a single Action passed to `BeginInvoke`.)

**Edit**

In Silverlight it is impossible to wait for a Dispatcher operation to complete, so you must refactor your code not to depend on it.

Comment: silverlight doesn't contain method Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: pff...what to refactor if I need to dowload information, write it to file and then read file and get result every 15 seconds?I can't use MessageBox and HtmlPage.Window.Invoke inside threads.

Comment: but how can I know when It recieved and when not? I need to update data on program's screen every 15 seconds.

Comment: because when program starts - it read data from file. And user can see this data on screen.
while he can see it download info every 15 seconds and then update screen. and I can't use(or maybe can but I think it is not good) to use @forever loop@ inside constructor of Page

Answer (score 1):

BeginInvoke schedules the action for asynchronous execution.  So by the time the value is assigned to settings, the current function has probably exited and settings is no longer visible.  If you want to wait until it completes, you need to use the return value of BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => settings = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ReadFile", new object[] { path1 }) as string));
```

What happens if check access returns true? you dont execute any code in that case, thats what happens so, your IF statement is super weird.

Also whats the purpose of thread.sleep(15sec) in the beginning of method?

If you really want to assign local variable `settings` to result of that execution you can create a ManualResetEvent, pass it with delegate for dispatcher invocation, and Set it after assignment is done.
Then after calling beginInvoke() you wait for you event to fire , and once it fires your settings will be assigned.

Although it all requires big refactoring I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming which turns sane logic into insane looking spaghetti code.

Instead of doing this:

```
string settings = "";
if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    settings = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ReadFile", new object[] { path1 }) as string));
// use settings here...
```

do this

```
string settings = "";
if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    settings = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ReadFile", new object[] { path1 }) as string)
    // use settings here ...
  }
) else {
    settings = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ReadFile", new object[] { path1 }) as string)
    // use settings here ...
};
```